# Does detailed cloud watch monitoring on Auto Scaling cost me extra money?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudwatch

https://aws.amazon.com/cloudwatch/details/#aws-element-7f11f2a8-f306-41c4-b081-1a8e7f39b3501
This document said no additional charge for Auto scaling groups, but does it mean no additional charge for installing software or no additional charge for detailed monitoring? Because when I tried to enable detailed monitoring on Auto scaling groups, that page implied that it will cost me extra money. So I guess the document I paste up there is trying to say no additional fee for installing software ?.........

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The document says:

> No additional software needs to be installed.

This means, you do not need to install any software to get extra Auto Scaling metrics in CloudWatch.

> **Auto Scaling groups:** seven pre-selected metrics at one-minute frequency, optional and for no additional charge.

When using Auto Scaling, you will get 7 metrics (of Amazon's choice) for free, at 1 minute intervals.

This has nothing to do with EC2 "Detailed Monitoring".

For EC2, "Basic Monitoring" includes 7 metrics (of Amazon's choice) for free, at 5 minute intervals.

"Detailed Monitoring" will increase frequency of these same 7 metrics from 5 minutes to 1 minute. But there is an extra charge for this.

Enabling "Detailed Monitoring" on your Auto Scaling group, will trickle down to the EC2 instances, so in essence, you are enabling "Detailed Monitoring" on the EC2 instances managed by your Auto Scaling group.

So yes, there will be an extra charge for enabling "Detailed Monitoring" on your Auto Scaling group.

Comment: Thanks for replying. "When using Auto Scaling, you will get 7 metrics (of Amazon's choice) for free, at 1 minute intervals" so even if I don't enable detailed monitoring on ec2 instances, I'll get information from monitoring auto scaling group every minute for free, but not about ec2 instances ?

Comment: You will get the 7 Auto Scaling metrics (1 minute intervals), and the 7 "Basic Monitoring" EC2 metrics (5 minute intervals).

Comment: Thank you for explanation !